# How to install libgdal on openSUSE 11.3?

Tags: linux, installation, opensuse, gdal

**libgdal**

```
linux-y3pi:~ # rpm -Uvh libgdal1-1.8.0-1.59.src.rpm 
warning: libgdal1-1.8.0-1.59.src.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1abd1afb: NOKEY
   1:libgdal1               ########################################### [100%]
linux-y3pi:~ #
```

**libgdal-devel**

```
linux-y3pi:~ # rpm -Uvh libgdal-devel-1.8.0-1.59.x86_64.rpm 
warning: libgdal-devel-1.8.0-1.59.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 1abd1afb: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
     libgdal1 = 1.8.0-1.59 is needed by libgdal-devel-1.8.0-1.59.x86_64
```

Of course *libgdal-devel* needs other dependencies too, but why isn't it able to see *libgdal*.

```
linux-y3pi:~ # whereis libgdal
libgdal: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.la /usr/local/lib/libgdal.a /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so
```

Of course, this is not in path:

```
linux-y3pi:~ # $PATH
bash: /home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin/:/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/bin:/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin:/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/qt/bin/:/home/anisha/qtsdk-2010.05/bin:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/home/anisha/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games: No such file or directory
```

I did: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as root, didn't help.
Where do I install this `libgdal` now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> # rpm -Uvh libgdal1-1.8.0-1.59.src.rpm
> ```

The "src" indicates that it's a source RPM. You need to find the binary RPM, specifically (probably) the x86_64 RPM. It will have a similar name, except it will say "x86_64" instead.

Comment: yes, thanks for reminding. I'll do that. With so many dependencies, this is indeed a daunting task!